# Two strings are not matching?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying 'Bacon' and 'Ваcon' string to compare but not match those string. What i have to do for match those two string

```
a = 'Bacon'
b = 'Ваcon'

if a==b:
    print('Match')
else:
   print('Not Match')
```

Comment: String `b` contains ["Cyrillic Capital Letter Ve"](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/1042) and ["Cyrillic Small Letter A"](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/1072).

Comment: try to copy value of a to b and run script again.

Answer (score 0):

`a` consists of five Latin characters.

`b` consists of two Cyrillic characters that happen to share shape with Latin characters "Ba", and three Latin characters.

To match them, you would have to have a database of "which characters look alike" (i.e. [`confusablesSummary`](http://www.unicode.org/Public/security/revision-03/confusablesSummary.txt)), and replace the impostors, before the comparison.

Comment: No - that falls out of scope of the answer. Try to write it yourself, it should not be too hard. If you have a _specific_ problem, post a question.

Answer (score 0):

I do see that the first two characters in both `a` and `b` are **not same**.

I tried printing the **ord()** values of characters in `a` and `b`.

This is what I got.

```
>>> a = 'Bacon'
>>> b = 'Ваcon'
>>> a==b
False
>>> for i in a:
...     print(ord(i))
... 
66
97
99
111
110
>>> for i in b:
...     print(ord(i))
... 
1042
1072
99
111
110
>>>
```

Comment: They are not ASCII values. ASCII goes only up to `127`; `1042` for `B` is Unicode.